# gdal_translate crashes on huge jp2

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, jpeg-2000

I have 44GB jp2 file, I want to translate it to tif file, but once it reaches 10% it crashes. No messages, just stopped. This is my command:

```
gdal_translate.exe -of GTiff  --config GDAL_CACHMAX 8000 -co COMPRESS=JPEG 
-co TILED=YES  -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR  -co JPEG_QUALITY=75 "Z:\Sat\inp.jp2" 
"C:\Shamaal\out.tif"
```

Comment: Might be running out of memory - have you looked at Task Manager or Resource Monitor while it's running to see how much RAM is used up as it goes?

Comment: Check which JPEG2000 drivers you have installed with `gdalinfo --formats` and add that into your question. There may be many, list them all.

Comment: `GDAL_CACHEMAX` instead of `GDAL_CACHMAX`, but setting it to 8000 is unlikely to work unless you have a 64 bit OS and a very new GDAL. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_CACHEMAX

Comment: I have 64bit OS and have 24 GB memory, I was monitoring the memory all the time, and it never exceed the 2GB used by GDAL.

Answer (score 1):

A 44GB jp2 is going to be a **monster** TIFF file. Assuming you really want that, I would expect the problem is that GDAL is using the OpenJPEG JP2 driver by default, and this isn't so up to snuff for such a large file.

Try using the `GDAL_SKIP` environment variable, described on the [GDAL Options](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDALOptions) page, to skip the `JPEG2000` driver in an attempt to have the file open up with the MrSID or ECW driver instead.

```
set GDAL_SKIP=JPEG2000
gdal_translate.exe ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This recent blog at http://blog.hexagongeospatial.com/jpeg2000-quirks/ covers a lot of the pitfalls between the available JPEG2000 toolkits. Since you are decoding a very large file, you will likely be running into the same compatibility issues that are likely solved by using JP2ECW or JP2MrSID (As [Howard alluded to](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172683/115)).